# C function name-dependent segfault with Python ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm getting a really weird crash when using ctypes in Python, but I'm not sure if the problem comes from Python or C.

Here is the C source (in `test.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void compress(char *a, int b) {
  printf("inside\n");
}

void run() {
  printf("before\n");
  compress("hi", 2);
  printf("after\n");
}
```

Then here's what happens when I call `run()` with ctypes:

```
$ python -c 'import ctypes; ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./test.so").run()'
before
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The weirdest thing is that the crash doesn't happen when I rename `compress()` to anything else.

Other things that prevent it from crashing:

- Calling `compress()` directly
- Calling `run()` or `compress()` from C directly (If I add a `main()`, compile it directly, and execute it)
- Removing either argument from the signature of `compress()` (but then the function doesn't seem to execute, based on the lack of "`inside`" being printed.

I'm pretty new to C, so I'm assuming there's something I'm missing here. What could be causing this?

System info:
Python 2.7.6
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
Ubuntu 14.04
`uname -r`: 3.13.0-58-generic

Comment: This sounds like there's a different `compress` function that ends up being called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While @falsetru has diagnosed the problem, his solution won't work in the general case where you have a lot of files to statically link together (because the entire point of declaring things static is to not have them visible from other files).

And while @eryksun has posted a solution for when you *want* to declare a function the same name as another, in general, you may have a lot of C functions you don't want to export, and you don't want to have to worry about whether they collide with some random function in some library that Python happens to import, and you don't want to have to prefix every one of your internal functions with an attribute.

(GCC maintains [documentation on function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), including this function visibility feature.)

A more general solution to avoiding namespace collisions is to tell the linker not to export any symbols by default, and then to mark only those functions you want exported, like run(), as visible.

There is probably a standard way to define the macro for this, but my C is so out-of-date I wouldn't know it.  In any case, this will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("protected")))

void compress(char *a, int b) {
  printf("inside\n");
}

EXPORT void run() {
  printf("before\n");
  compress("hi", 2);
  printf("after\n");
}
```

You can link and run it like this:

```
$ gcc -x c test.c --shared -fvisibility=hidden -o test.so
$ python -c 'import ctypes; ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./test.so").run()'
before
inside
after
```

Comment: This is great. I wish there was an answer I could accept that incorporated the work of all 3 of you (you, @falsetru, and @eryksun)!

Answer (score 6):

According to the debugging, the program is trying to call `compress` in `libz.so.1`.

```
$ gdb python -c core
...
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `python -c import ctypes; ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./test.so").run()'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f9ddea18bff in compress2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
```

which accepts different parameters (`zlib.h`):

```
ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT compress OF((Bytef *dest,   uLongf *destLen,
                                 const Bytef *source, uLong sourceLen));

ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT compress2 OF((Bytef *dest,   uLongf *destLen,
                                  const Bytef *source, uLong sourceLen,
                                  int level));
/*
```

You can modify the `compress` function to be `static` to work around the issue:

```
static void compress(char *a, int b)
{
    printf("inside\n");
}
```

Comment: If `compress` should be exported, you can use a gcc [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to mark the symbol visibility as protected, e.g. `void __attribute__ ((visibility("protected"))) compress(char *a, int b)`. Via `readelf -s test.so` you'll see the symbol visibility as `PROTECTED`. This way you can still call `compress` via ctypes, which you can't do if you make it `static`.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that somehow it was colliding with another function named `compress`. But I'm still not clear on how. Does it involve libraries the Python interpreter uses? How is a function from there getting into the namespace of my ctypes-imported library?

Comment: @NickS, C doesn't let you control symbol visibility other than making a symbol `static` to a file. Thus your `compress` function has "default" visibility, which allows it to be overridden. Using "hidden" is preferred for non-API functions since it forces the binding to local instead of global, which is more efficient. Using "default" visibility is preferred for exported APIs; just use a unique prefix. "protected" is the most expensive implementation (because C function pointers). Read "How To Write Shared Libraries",Ulrich Drepper, 2011.